# Cassandra & Spark: can I add an item to a row to create a dataframe from a list of Rows

Tags: java, apache-spark, cassandra, apache-spark-sql

I'm using an API to get a result from a dataframe.

Basically my dataframe contains name, firstname and date of birth

```
String myquery = "SELECT name, firstname, dateobirth FROM tableA"
```

I use an API to get the adress of this person (this AP

```
    > List<Row> dataRows = new ArrayList<Row>();
            dataRows = dframe.collectAsList();*




for (Row row : dataRows){
            requestAnswer = row.getString(0) + " " + row.getString(1) + " " + row.getString(2);
            Result result = myapi(requestanswer);

            if (result.length > 0){

                System.out.println(result);

            }
```

I 'd like to get a dataframe with the name, firsname, dateofbirth and the result.

How can I add this result in the row?

Is there a better way to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

Different options if your api call is quick and does not require external resources like a http connection to some rest service:

1. `withColumn` with a udf to call your service
2. `.map` function on the dataframe to transform the Row

If api call is involve external resources:

3. call `mapPartitions` and create your connection there.